# How do I deserialize JSON documents into pre-processed beans in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to figure out how to combine the code generator I use in my project and Jackson so that I could combine them both.
The third-party bean code generator does some things that I would like to improve.
For example, the class below

```java
public class Wrapper {

    public String string;
    public List<String> array;

}
```

does not have default values set for both `string` and `array`.
Under some circumstances (and mostly due to **heavy** legacy reasons) I'd like Jackson to deserialize the above bean class with the default values set if they are not provided in the input JSON document.
For example, I'd like `{"string": "foo"}` to be deserialized to a bean as if the source JSON were `{"string":"foo","array":[]}` so that it would result in a bean with two non-null fields.
The first idea I came up with is creating a bean instance, then run a "set default fields" preprocessor, and then read the JSON into the constructed and initialized bean.

```java
public final class DefaultsModule
        extends SimpleModule {

    @Override
    public void setupModule(final SetupContext setupContext) {
        setupContext.addBeanDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
            @Override
            public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(final DeserializationConfig config, final BeanDescription description,
                    final JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer) {
                return DefaultFieldsJsonDeserializer.create(description.getType(), description);
            }
        });
    }

    private static final class DefaultFieldsJsonDeserializer<T>
            extends JsonDeserializer<T> {

        // the generated classes set is finite, so won't bother with subclassing
        private static final Map<Class<?>, Supplier<?>> NEW_INSTANCES = new ImmutableMap.Builder<Class<?>, Supplier<?>>()
                .put(Iterable.class, ArrayList::new)
                .put(Collection.class, ArrayList::new)
                .put(List.class, ArrayList::new)
                .put(ArrayList.class, ArrayList::new)
                .put(LinkedList.class, LinkedHashMap::new)
                .put(Map.class, LinkedHashMap::new)
                .put(HashMap.class, HashMap::new)
                .put(LinkedHashMap.class, LinkedHashMap::new)
                .put(TreeMap.class, TreeMap::new)
                .put(Set.class, LinkedHashSet::new)
                .put(HashSet.class, HashSet::new)
                .put(LinkedHashSet.class, LinkedHashSet::new)
                .put(TreeSet.class, TreeSet::new)
                .build();

        private final BeanDescription description;
        private final Iterable<? extends Map.Entry<Field, ? extends Supplier<?>>> fieldDefaultsChain;

        private DefaultFieldsJsonDeserializer(final BeanDescription description,
                final Iterable<? extends Map.Entry<Field, ? extends Supplier<?>>> fieldDefaultsChain) {
            this.description = description;
            this.fieldDefaultsChain = fieldDefaultsChain;
        }

        private static <T> JsonDeserializer<T> create(final JavaType javaType, final BeanDescription description) {
            final Iterable<? extends Map.Entry<Field, ? extends Supplier<?>>> fieldDefaultsChain = Stream.of(javaType.getRawClass().getDeclaredFields())
                    .filter(field -> NEW_INSTANCES.containsKey(field.getType()))
                    .peek(field -> field.setAccessible(true))
                    .map(field -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Field, Supplier<Object>>(field, () -> NEW_INSTANCES.get(field.getType()).get()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new DefaultFieldsJsonDeserializer<>(description, fieldDefaultsChain);
        }

        @Override
        @Nullable
        public T deserialize(final JsonParser parser, final DeserializationContext context)
                throws IOException {
            try {
                // instantiate the bean
                @Nullable
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final T bean = (T) description.instantiateBean(false);
                if ( bean == null ) {
                    return null;
                }
                // do default values pre-processing
                for ( final Map.Entry<Field, ? extends Supplier<?>> e : fieldDefaultsChain ) {
                    final Field field = e.getKey();
                    final Object defaultValue = e.getValue().get();
                    field.set(bean, defaultValue);
                }
                // since the object is constructed and initialized properly, simply update it
                final ObjectReader objectReader = ((ObjectMapper) parser.getCodec())
                        .readerForUpdating(bean);
                return objectReader.readValue(parser);
            } catch ( final IllegalAccessException ex ) {
                return context.reportBadTypeDefinition(description, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

In short, I'd like the following unit test to pass:

```java
public final class DefaultsModuleTest {

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    private static final class Generated {

        @JsonProperty
        private String string;

        @JsonProperty
        private List<String> array /*not generated but should be initialized in the pre-processor = new ArrayList<>()*/;

    }

    @Test
    public void test()
            throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new DefaultsModule());
        final Generated expected = new Generated("foo", Collections.emptyList());
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, objectMapper.readValue("{\"string\":\"foo\"}", Generated.class));
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, objectMapper.readValue("{\"string\":\"foo\",\"array\":null}", Generated.class));
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, objectMapper.readValue("{\"string\":\"foo\",\"array\":[]}", Generated.class));
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the deserializer above runs in the infinite recursion loop.
So I have multiple questions:

- how to implement it properly?
- maybe I should go with `ValueInstantiator` somehow?
- what is a generic way to get the delegate JSON deserializer? (Gson allows to obtain delegate type adapters in type adapter factories, Jackson offers the deserializer modifier approach but the `JsonDeserializer` coming in the modifier causes weird exceptions + not sure if it can update existing objects).

My Jackson databind version is 2.9.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have realized the way it had to be done properly. I didn't notice that I can add value instantiators I mentioned above to the module setup context. Having it configured, I simply don't need to create a custom deserializer since I can supply constructed+initialized values myself.

```java
public final class DefaultsModule
        extends SimpleModule {

    @Override
    public void setupModule(final SetupContext setupContext) {
        setupContext.addValueInstantiators((config, description, defaultInstantiator) -> DefaultFieldsInstantiator.isSupported(description.getBeanClass())
                ? DefaultFieldsInstantiator.create(config, description)
                : defaultInstantiator
        );
    }

    private static final class DefaultFieldsInstantiator
            extends StdValueInstantiator {

        private static final Map<Class<?>, Supplier<?>> NEW_INSTANCES = new ImmutableMap.Builder<Class<?>, Supplier<?>>()
                .put(Iterable.class, ArrayList::new)
                .put(Collection.class, ArrayList::new)
                .put(List.class, ArrayList::new)
                .put(ArrayList.class, ArrayList::new)
                .put(LinkedList.class, LinkedHashMap::new)
                .put(Map.class, LinkedHashMap::new)
                .put(HashMap.class, HashMap::new)
                .put(LinkedHashMap.class, LinkedHashMap::new)
                .put(TreeMap.class, TreeMap::new)
                .put(Set.class, LinkedHashSet::new)
                .put(HashSet.class, HashSet::new)
                .put(LinkedHashSet.class, LinkedHashSet::new)
                .put(TreeSet.class, TreeSet::new)
                .build();

        private final BeanDescription description;
        private final Iterable<? extends Map.Entry<Field, ? extends Supplier<?>>> fieldDefaultsChain;

        private DefaultFieldsInstantiator(final DeserializationConfig config, final BeanDescription description,
                final Iterable<? extends Map.Entry<Field, ? extends Supplier<?>>> fieldDefaultsChain) {
            super(config, description.getType());
            this.description = description;
            this.fieldDefaultsChain = fieldDefaultsChain;
        }

        private static boolean isSupported(final Class<?> clazz) {
            return ...............;
        }

        private static ValueInstantiator create(final DeserializationConfig config, final BeanDescription description) {
            final Iterable<? extends Map.Entry<Field, ? extends Supplier<?>>> fieldDefaultsChain = Stream.of(description.getType().getRawClass().getDeclaredFields())
                    .filter(field -> NEW_INSTANCES.containsKey(field.getType()))
                    .peek(field -> field.setAccessible(true))
                    .map(field -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Field, Supplier<Object>>(field, () -> NEW_INSTANCES.get(field.getType()).get()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new DefaultFieldsInstantiator(config, description, fieldDefaultsChain);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canCreateUsingDefault() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        @Nullable
        public Object createUsingDefault(final DeserializationContext context)
                throws JsonMappingException {
            try {
                @Nullable
                final Object bean = description.instantiateBean(false);
                if ( bean == null ) {
                    return null;
                }
                for ( final Map.Entry<Field, ? extends Supplier<?>> e : fieldDefaultsChain ) {
                    final Field field = e.getKey();
                    final Object defaultValue = e.getValue().get();
                    field.set(bean, defaultValue);
                }
                return bean;
            } catch ( final IllegalAccessException ex ) {
                return context.reportBadDefinition(description.getType(), "Cannot set field: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And all the following tests pass:

```java
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new DefaultsModule());
Assertions.assertNull(objectMapper.readValue("null", Generated.class));
Assertions.assertEquals(new Generated(null, Collections.emptyList()), objectMapper.readValue("{}", Generated.class));
Assertions.assertEquals(new Generated(null, ImmutableList.of("bar")), objectMapper.readValue("{\"array\":[\"bar\"]}", Generated.class));
Assertions.assertEquals(new Generated("foo", Collections.emptyList()), objectMapper.readValue("{\"string\":\"foo\"}", Generated.class));
Assertions.assertEquals(new Generated("foo", null), objectMapper.readValue("{\"string\":\"foo\",\"array\":null}", Generated.class));
Assertions.assertEquals(new Generated("foo", Collections.emptyList()), objectMapper.readValue("{\"string\":\"foo\",\"array\":[]}", Generated.class));
```